# Repo import readline error

Tags: android, ubuntu, repository

I have tried to work with Android as described in http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html, but when I used repo, I have faced with this error:
 import readline
ImportError: No module named readline

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and Python 2.7.

I will be appreciated if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libreadline5-dev`

Answer (score 0):

The readline is not avaliable becase the python installed with out readline module. You need to recompile your Python with readline included. You can do it like this, good luck!

$ source Install_Python2.7.5.sh

Shell script "Install_Python2.7.5.sh" is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev

sudo aptitude install build-essential libreadline5-dev

sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev

if [ ! -d ~/software/Python/Python-2.7.5 ]; then

    mkdir ~/software
    mkdir ~/software/Python
    mkdir ~/software/Python/Python-2.7.5
fi

if [ ! -d ~/bin ]; then

    mkdir ~/bin
fi

user_root=~

echo $user_root

echo "unpackage Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2..."

tar -jxvf Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2 

echo "prepear to install Python-2.7.5"

cd Python-2.7.5

sed -i "s/#readline/readline/g" Modules/Setup.dist

echo "Start to install Python-2.7.5"

./configure --prefix=$user_root/software/Python/Python-2.7.5/  && make && make install

echo "Make symbol link"

ln -s -f $user_root/software/Python/Python-2.7.5/bin/* $user_root/bin

echo "Set environment variable"

PATH=$user_root/bin:$PATH
```